# Heroku App doesn't have option to push to "promote to production" but has option to "move app to production"

Tags: reactjs, heroku, frontend, continuous-integration, website-hosting

Like the title says, it doesn't have the option to promote to production which is really weird since it used to have that in the rectangular block. Tried doing research on what is the difference between the two and havent found anything yet. The block on the right is the production block. Has anyone came across this weirdness before?

[image]